# 'background-position' on 'background-color' with CSS

Tags: html, css, background-color

I'm trying to use 'bakground-position' in the background of my div, but not working. 
When background an image, the 'background-position' works, but with 'background-color' is not working. 
What can I do?

This is my CSS:

```
#defaultContent {
    width: 983px;
    min-height: 382px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    background-position: right 50px;
}
```

Comment: background-position is tied to background image, not color

Comment: When you have a background color background-position will not do anything as the whole area is filled equally. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can't position a `background-color`. `background-position` is for positioning, well, a background-image. Do you have a background-image you are trying to position? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can workaround with a `div` only for background, simulating it by mixing `position: absolute` offsets and negative `z-index`.. (Though I've tested only in chrome)

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8QWj/)

HTML

```
<div id="defaultContentParent">
    <div id="defaultContent"></div>
    <div id="defaultContentContent"><div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#defaultContentParent {
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    background-color: #aaa;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;    
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

#defaultContent {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        right: 0;
    width: 80px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#defaultContentContent {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an background-image as a solid color, creating a monochrome gradient:

```
#defaultContent {
    width: 983px;
    min-height: 382px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000);
    background-position: right 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The gradient is fully compatible with an image, and if you set both colors to the same, it is fully equivalent to a solid color

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UxXSz/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't position a `background-color` property, since that property fills the entire space. Likewise, you can't use `background-color` with a background image, because that would, basically, replace your background image with the filled `background-color`, at which point there is no reason to use a background image at all!

Are you perhaps thinking of using a gradient, or giving a background image a filter of a certain filter? That would be a different question.